# Can I run Bash scripts in FreeBSD without modifying them?

Tags: bash, shell-script, freebsd, portability

Correct me if I'm wrong:

- "sh" script != "bash" script
- Linux script are written in Bash
- Bash script usually `#!/bin/sh`
- In GNU/Linux, `/bin/sh` is Bash
- In FreeBSD, `/bin/sh` is not bash, it's the true `sh`

So if I want to use a Linux script in FreeBSD, and I run `./script.sh` in the shell, it will run the Bash script in "sh" and not Bash, since `/bin/sh` in FreeBSD is not Bash.

Is there a way I could run those Bash scripts, without modifying it? So no modification to the `#!/bin/sh` statement in the script file to point somewhere else?

I would like to run Bash script trough Zsh, if possible. Don't want to install Bash, and since Zsh can run Bash scripts...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Comment: Saying "I want to run a `bash` script without installing `bash`" is equivalent of saying "I want to run a Python script without installing Python".  If it's a `bash` script, it should be executed using a `bash` interpreter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call your favorite shell with the script as a parameter.

```
bash ./script.sh
```

Comment: "Don't want to install Bash" - OP doesn't want to run bash.

Comment: well it could be zsh too, thats why i wrote "favorite shell"

Comment: But, without calling the program bash (or zsh) with a script as an argument? In the last resort, I could do that, but the `./filetoexecute.sh` is faster to write, than `bash filetoexecute.sh` or `zsh filetoexecute.sh`. Also, Strange the way you say it... bash ./something... Never saw someone using the ./ as an argument

Comment: Another option would be to modify your system to install zsh as /bin/sh.

Comment: @arved Of course, after you've made _sure_ that this change does not break _any_ system scripts.

Comment: Note that while this solution will execute `script.sh` with the selected shell, any script called from within that script, will still default to the shebang given in the script.

Answer (score 3):

I run FreeBSD myself. I found that starting the script with the following greatly improves cross OS compatibility:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: While that is correct and helpful when writing a new script it does not really answer the question here. The OP asked explicitly for a solution where already existing files do not need to be edited before they can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You asked to correct you when you were wrong. I'll try:

- *Linux scripts are written in bash*: Well, some are written for `bash`, others for `dash` and hopefully a lot potable for any POSIX-compliant shell.
- *Bash script usually #!/bin/sh* If they rely on non-standard `bash` features, it is highly recommended to have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang
- *In GNU/Linux, /bin/sh is Bash* That depends on the distribution. It can also be `dash` or `mksh` on Debian for instance.
- *In FreeBSD, /bin/sh is not bash, it's the true sh*. There is a lot of `sh` implementations. Which one is "true"? On FreeBSD, `sh` is based on the Almquist shell like `dash` or NetBSD `sh`. On OpenBSD, it's based on `pdksh`, on many commercial Unices, it's based on ksh88 (which is the basis for the Unix/POSIX `sh` specification). Some `ksh88`-based shells and `bash` are the only two shells that have been certified as being a Unix compliant `sh` implementation (when built with the right flags and in when in the right environment).

If you have scripts with `/bin/sh` shebang and want them to be executed by `zsh` you can try passing the script to `zsh`, but this will fail as soon as this script calls another script (and you don't want to modify it).

So I only see the possibility to have a symbolic link from `/bin/sh` to your `zsh`. **But I don't recommend to do this**, as it may have drastic impact on your boot time and will not even help you for some of your linux scripts.

Comment: Note that while I wouldn't recommend installing `zsh` as `/bin/sh` either, it may not impact boot time that drastically. Thanks to its modular design, it's leaner than `bash`. It's also generally faster than `bash` and has some optimisations that some otherwise leaner/faster shells like `dash` don't have (like optimizing out some forks). On FreeBSD though, changing sh to bash or zsh would indeed affect performance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for you edit and for this clarification. That's what I meant: Not `zsh` instead of `bash`, but instead of a fast scripting shell. Another problem not yet addressed here is that scripts for linux and not tested anywhere else may use GNU extensions on standard tools., so even installing `bash` would not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to run Linux based written script using `/bin/bash` in FreeBSD without modifying them, then you can simply copy `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/bin/bash` at FreeBSD and it will work.

Comment: A symlink would be better. Otherwise, /bin/bash would not automatically be updated when /usr/local/bin/bash is updated.